# Python Dictionary Pickling

Tags: python

this is my code but can't use pickle to load it afterwords, also think it is pretty inefficient, thanks.
The write file:

```
import pickle

cont="yes"
u_ele_stu={}
ele_pl_stu={}
x=len(u_ele_stu)
y=len(ele_pl_stu)

with open("Tennis Scores.txt" ,"wb") as a:
while cont=="yes":
    age=input("Would you like to add to under 11 list or 11-16? (under 11 / 11-16)")
    if age=="under 11":
        name=input("Input the name of a student: ")
        pos=str(input("Input the last position they achieved in a tournament"))
        u_ele_stu[x+1]=name, " ", pos
    elif age=="11-16":
        name=input("Input the name of a student: ")
        pos=str(input("Input the last position they achieved in a tournament"))
        ele_pl_stu[y+1]=name, " ", pos
    cont=input("Would you like to add another student? yes/no")
    cont.lower()
if cont!="yes":
    pickle.dump(u_ele_stu, a)
    pickle.dump(ele_pl_stu, a)
```

The read file:

```
import pickle

with open("Tennis Scores.txt", "r") as a:
    b=pickle.load(a)
    c=pickle.load(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
```

Comment: Are you sure your indentation is correct?

Comment: Also don't use spaces in filenames. Or at least escape the spaces.

Comment: You think it is Inefficient compared to what?

Answer (score 0):

Try dumping each object in a separate file:

```
with open('u_ele_stu.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(u_ele_stu, f)

with open('ele_pl_stu.txt', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(ele_pl_stu, f)
```

Answer (score 0):

**I fixed the problem by adding b to "r", I don't think this is the most efficient way, though, it just werkz...**

> with open("Tennis Scores.txt", "r***b***") as a:

Comment: That's the way you do it. You write binary data, so you have to read binary data.